# Angular - How to check if user is allowed before loading the view?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app. I am using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage my states. I need to call a common API to check whether the user is allowed to view the web page or not. Is there a common place where I can call the API and only then proceed to the state the user is requesting for?

With my current implementation, the view partially gets displayed and then the reroute happens.

```
//app.js

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, toState) {

    if(toState.name === 'login' || toState.name === 'payment')
        return;

    userService.isBillingCleared().then(function() {
        //redirect to toState
    }, function() {
        $state.go('payment');
    });
});
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: maybe using `$routeChangeStart` instead of `$stateChangeSuccess` could help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) { 

  if(toState.name === 'login' || toState.name === 'payment')
    return;

  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the state change 

  userService.isBillingCleared().then(function() {
    $state.go(toState.name); // do the state change manually if allowed
  }, function() {
    $state.go('payment');
  });
}));
```

Comment: How does it not work? I've used similar code to do the same thing you are trying to achieve, did you check if the event is being fired and the values are as expected?

Comment: The page shows up for a fraction of a second and then gets redirected to the payment state. I did try removing the API call and redirecting to the state directly. Still didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Try this link which talks about [authentication](http://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/require-authentication-for-certain-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs) for routes in ui-router. Seems like this would be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while developing a system and the only difference was that I was using default router that is provided by angular but obviously that wont cause any problem.

Keep the data hidden before checking the authentication level of the user and make directive to centralize the whole process. Let's imagine it this way - the view in question that you'll be showing to the user is hidden unless the details are being checked and until then show them any preloader or something or whatever animation you want to.

This is what generally people do in case of a web app or any mobile application, clog the data unless you are sure that yes the data is ready to be viewed.

This practice can be useful even in use case where you are loading the data after the page is being loaded, for e.g. let's say I am showing transactions to user but the transactions are loaded only after the user calls for the view so a call to the backend is made when the view is called that means the user can see for a split second only - an empty table. So...just make use of a preloader and call for the function first and then let the user see the table.